# Send DataTable complete or use .Select first?

Tags: c#, datatable

I am sending over quite a lot of DataTables between public voids and just wonder, what is the most efficient, use .Select in the parent function or send over the complete DataTable and use select in the child function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you are only passing between library functions, since its reference *(address of reference)* would only be passed, not all the values.

It would only matter if you are passing those across web services or to some other process.

Comment: C# Value and Reference Types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

It's more a question of responsibility than technical correctness.  Does it make more sense for the function do decide what records/fields to select or for the caller?

If you already have all of the data in memory, the memory usage and performance should be about the same either way.